# Building a website without page reload, using new HTML5 history mechanics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history, pushstate

I was looking for a way to change browser address location without causing a full page reload, thus I got some useful information, like this:

http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

and trying to get into the new HTML5 history mechanics I got also this:

[HTML5/jQuery: pushState and popState - deep linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776614/html5-jquery-pushstate-and-popstate-deep-linking)

so a completely different idea came to mind ...

I'm asking if there could be a possible way (I don't necessarily mean "easy") to build, or if there already exists something like a "framework" or similar, to build a web project that's able to completely avoid page reloads.... thus making intensive use of ajax and/or jquery etc. (I cite this because it's what I usually work with).

I think this could improve the "user experience" when browsing such kinds of site.

Comment: The concept you are referring to is known as "Single Page Application" you can search on your favorite search engine to find many frameworks and much related information on the subject.

Comment: Checkout Knockout.js: http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: You're asking how to about change from `page1.html` to `page2.html` by loading the contents of `page2.html` into `page1.html` with ajax, and then updating the address bar and browser history. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it's such what knockout does and what SPA is.
@Quintin Robinson:  thank you, I was not knowing under these terms before

Comment: @kevin boucher: thank you, it's a good **live** example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The bbUI toolkit is designed to progressively enhance its capability based on the abilities of the Web rendering engine on BB5/BB6/BB7/PlayBook and BlackBerry 10. [...] By not adding any kind of layout logic to the screen elements, bbUI can then modify the DOM in any way that it needs in order to achieve the desired result.

All DOM manipulation occurs while the HTML fragment is not attached to the live DOM. This allows DOM manipulation to occur VERY, VERY, FAST and it does not incur any WebView layout computation until the entire fragment is inserted into the DOM. Layout computation during JavaScript DOM manipulation is one of the single most expensive operations that can slow down a Web based UI.

Each screen you create is an HTML fragment that gets loaded into the application via AJAX to keep the size of the DOM small and memory usage to a minimum.'

https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub](https://github.com/) is built this way. When you're within a project and you click on a link (like "bin"), it loads new content that corresponds to that link and updates the address bar URL, but the page itself doesn't reload.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out http://backbonejs.org/ it should help on both of your requirement client side binding and browser history.