# Issue with using html5 API popState and pushState specially in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, html5-history

I'm working on an Ajax-based website...
In my site, every single page will load from other script into one of my `DIV`s using jQuery Ajax...
So, as you know, I need to use `HTML5 History API` for some reasons...
You can find my sample page on [THIS LINK...](http://ksvahed.ir/kiyarash/index2.php)

I made some `images` for `help`, because my page is in `Persian` and you may couldn't find out my mean..
**This is the image:**
[image: image for help]

As you may found out, I tried to make something like `windows8`...

**And this is the story:**
1/ When user click on cubes, they will transform `360 deg` and became full screen...
2/ The related content will get from another file using `jQuery Ajax method` and insert to this `div`...
3/ The `location bar` hash will change with `HTML5 history API`--->`pushState`...
4/ Page title will updated using `$('title').html(myTitle)`...
5/ And `onpopstate function will defined`...
**Description:


A=> The cubes that marked with (( `don't work` )), don't have any `target page` for `Ajax request`, so they will destroy the page, on click...!!!

B=> Every thing works fine in `Firefox` and `Internet Explorer11` excep forward button...** 

Now my issues with this page:
**I=>** The `favicon` disappear in `google chrome33` and `opera20` and `Internet Explorer11` after `Ajax request` and when the page title will update...!!!
**II=>** When I click on the `back` button, the page will update correctly and every thing is fine, but when I click on `forward`, there is not any reaction and page will load without `css` and `js` files when refresh the new forwarded page...!!!
**I'm not sure next problems are because of html5 history API, and accept my apologize if it's true.**
 
[image: image for help]

**III=>** The `login form buttons` are disable in **google chrome** when a div is full screen, ...?!?!?
**IV=>** As you can see in the image above, inside the **`div.third`** mouseover event don't work, when the `product page` or `articles page` are full screen...**`( just in chrome )`**

**I know that my question was detailed and appreciate for your attention.**
Please guide me to right way for fixing this errors...

**I researched about `html5 history API` in links below:**
http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/series/html5-pushstate.html
http://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history
[HTML5/jQuery: pushState and popState - deep linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776614/html5-jquery-pushstate-and-popstate-deep-linking)
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#handler-window-onpopstate
http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-first-look-at-the-history-api--net-28053

***`EDIT :`***

**arian.js**

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    /*/----  C H E C K    I F    A L L IMAGES L O A D E D  ----/*/
    var total_images = $("body img").length;
    var percentPerImage = 100 / total_images;
    var images_loaded = 0;
    var percent = 0;
    $("body").children().not('.meter').hide();
    console.log('percentPerImage--> ' + percentPerImage);

    $("body").find('img').each(function() {
        var fakeSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        $("<img/>").attr("src", fakeSrc).css('display', 'none').load(function() {
            images_loaded++;
            percent += percentPerImage;

            $(".meter > span")//During image loading ProgressBar
                .animate({
                    width: percent + '%'
                }, 400);       //During image loading ProgressBar

            if (images_loaded >= total_images) {

                // now all images are loaded.

                $("body").children().show();
                $('.meter').hide();
                //$("body h1").hide();
            }//if (images_loaded 

        });//$("<img/>").attr("src"

    });//$("body").find
    /*/-----  C H E C K    I F    A L L IMAGES L O A D E D  ----/*/


    var WinWidth, WinHeight, HeaderHeight;

    $('#offer, #hamkaran, #middle_transparent').css('cursor', 'default');


    WinWidth = $(window).width();//دریافت عرض صفحه مرورگر
    WinHeight = $(window).height();//دریافت ارتفاع صفحه مرورگر
    HeaderHeight = $('#header').height();//ارتفاع هدر سایت

    $('html, body').css('height', WinWidth *2);
    if ( $('html, body').scrollTop() == WinWidth*2 ) {

    }
    /*/----  A R R O W    B U T T O N S    B E H A V I O R  ----/*/
  $('div.arrows').not('#part2_right, #part1_right, #part1_down').hide();
    $('#loginForm').hide();

    $(document).on('click', '#part2_right', function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: 850}, 500, 'easeOutQuint');
        $('#part2_left').fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#part1_right', function(){
        $('#part2_right').fadeOut('slow');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: 850}, 500, 'easeOutQuint');
        $('#part2_left').fadeIn('slow');
    });


    $(document).on('click', '#part2_left', function(){
        $('#part2_right, #part1_right').fadeIn('slow');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 500, 'easeOutQuint');/*easeInQuart*/ /*easeInOutQuint*/
        $('#part2_left').fadeOut('slow');
    });


    function downScroll() {
        $('html, body').stop(true).animate({scrollTop:WinWidth*2}, 800, 'easeInCubic', false).mousemove(function(e) {
         $('#bg3d').css({'left':e.pageX/40});
      });;
        $(this).one('click', upScroll);
        $('#part1_down').css({'background-image':'url(images/arrows/light/arrowTop.png)'});
    }
    function upScroll() {
        $('html, body').stop(true).animate({scrollTop:0}, 800, 'easeInOutCubic', false);
        $(this).one('click', downScroll);
        $('#part1_down').css({'background-image':'url(images/arrows/light/arrowBottom.png)'});
    }
    $('#part1_down').one('click', downScroll);

    /*/----  A R R O W    B U T T O N S    B E H A V I O R  ----/*/







    /*/-----  L O G    I N    B E H A V I O R  ----/*/
    function down() {
        $('#loginForm').slideDown('slow', 'easeOutQuint', false);
        $(this).one('click', up);
    }
    function up() {
        $('#loginForm').slideUp('slow', 'easeOutQuint', false);
        $(this).one('click', down);
    }
    $('#login').one('click', down)

    /*/------  L O G    I N    B E H A V I O R  -----/*/







    /*/-----  C L I C K    ON    DIV . M O R A B A  -----/*/
    $(document).on('click', 'div.moraba', function(e) {

              $('div.moraba, div.mostatil, div.big_moraba, div.arrows').not(this).stop(true).fadeOut('fast');


              $('html, body').css('overflow','hidden');

                if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'offer' || $(this).attr('id') == 'hamkaran' || $(this).attr('id') == 'middle_transparent' ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return; 
                };


                if ( $(this).css('width') == '120px' ) {
                    var detail = {};
                    detail.id               = $(this).attr('id');
                    detail.class           = $(this).attr('class').substr(7);
                    detail.htmlCode     = $(this).html();
                }
                else {
                    return; 
                };
                //alert(detail.htmlCode)


                if ( detail.class.substr(0,4) == 'part' ) {
                    $(this)
                            .animate({
                                width:         WinWidth,
                                height:           WinHeight,
                                marginTop:   -85,
                                marginLeft:  -263
                            }, 300, 'easeOutQuint', false)
                            .data({ id: detail.id, class: detail.class, htmlCode: detail.htmlCode})
                            .css('z-index',500)
                            .transition({rotateY:'360deg'}, 1500,'snap');

                    $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: 850})
                }
                else {

                    $(this)
                            .animate({
                                width:         WinWidth,
                                height:           WinHeight,
                                marginTop:   -85,
                                marginLeft:  -210
                            }, 300, 'easeOutQuint', false)
                            .data({ id: detail.id, class: detail.class, htmlCode: detail.htmlCode})
                            .css('z-index',500)
                            .transition({rotateY:'360deg'}, 1500,'snap');


            };


            var URL;
            switch ( $(this).attr('id') ) {
                case 'radif4_dovomi':
                      URL = 'pages/Ajax/maqhalat.php';
                      headerBar = '<span style="font-size:21px; color:rgb(25, 200, 243);">مقالات</span>';
                      break;
                case 'radif4_avali':
                      URL = 'pages/Ajax/download.php';
                      headerBar = '<span style="font-size:21px; color:rgb(130, 131, 255);">دانلود</span>';
                      break;
                case 'news':
                      URL = 'pages/Ajax/offer.php';
                      headerBar = '<span style="font-size:21px; color:#FB753C;">پیشنهاد ویژه</span>';
                      break;
                      /*
                case 'topRight' :
                      URL = 'pages/Ajax/contactUs.php';
                      headerBar = '<span style="font-size:21px; color:#FB753C;">پیشنهاد ویژه</span>';
                      break;
                      */ 
                case 'about':
                      URL = 'pages/Ajax/calculator.php';
                      headerBar = '<span style="font-size:21px; color:rgb(0, 158, 175);">محاسبه گر</span>';
                      break;
            }
            // = 'pages/Ajax/' + detail.id + '.php';



            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:URL,/*'http://localhost/Admin_arian_root/admin/pages/index_admin.php'*/
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#' + detail.id).html('<img src="images/icons/loadingLarg.gif" width="400" height="400" style="margin:auto;"  alt=""/>');
                    $('#cursor').html('<img src="images/icons/loader_light.gif" width="32" height="32"  alt=""/><span>لطفأ کمی صبر کنید</span>');
                },
                statusCode: {
                    404: function(){
                        $('#' + detail.id).html('<h1>صفحه مورد نظر  پیدا نشد</h1>')
                    }
                },
                cache:true,
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#' + detail.id).html(result).data({ajaxResult: result});

                    var currentAddressBar = window.location.pathname;
                      var titleIndex0 = result.indexOf('<title>');
                      var titleIndex1 = result.indexOf('</title>');
                      var title    = result.substring(titleIndex0 + 7, titleIndex1);

                    var hashBangIndex0 = URL.indexOf('.php');
                    var hash           = URL.substring(11, hashBangIndex0);

                    var thisID = detail.id;

                    window.history.pushState({page : title, id : thisID }, title, currentAddressBar + '/' + hash);

                    $('title').html(title);
                    console.log(currentAddressBar + '\n Title--> ' + title + '\n hash--> ' + hash + '\n State--> ' + window.history.state.page + '\n ID--> ' + thisID );

                     window.onpopstate = function(event){
                         Reset();
                         window.history.replaceState({ page : "رین البرز، نخستین سایت خرید و فروش محصولات سرمایشی و گرمایشی", id : null}, "آرین البرز / خانه",currentAddressBar);
                          //pushState({page : "آرین البرز، نخستین سایت خرید و فروش محصولات سرمایشی و گرمایشی"}, "آرین البرز، خانه", currentAddressBar);
                         $('title').html("آرین البرز، خانه");

                         console.log('The State---> ' + window.history.state.page + '\nThe Id--> ' + window.history.state.id );
                         //window.history.pushState(null, title, currentAddressBar);
                     }


                    //var headerBar = '<span>' + detail.id + '</span>';
                    $('#cursor').html(headerBar)
                }
            })

    })

    /*/----  C L I C K    ON    DIV . M O R A B A  ----/*/







    /*/-----  C L I C K    ON    DIV # L O G O  -----/*/
    $(document).on('click', 'div.mostatil#logo', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
          $('div.moraba, div.mostatil, div.big_moraba, div.arrows').not(this).stop(true).fadeOut('fast');

            //alert();
            if ( $(this).css('width') == '250px' ) {
                var detail = {};
                detail.id               = $(this).attr('id');
                detail.class           = $(this).attr('class').substr(7);
                detail.htmlCode     = $(this).html();
                detail.top            = $(this).css('top');
                detail.left          = $(this).css('left');

                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:"pages/Ajax/products.php",
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#logo').html('Loading, Please wait...')
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        404: function(){
                            $(this).html('صفحه مورد نظر پیدا نشد');
                        }
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#logo').html(result).css('background','none');
                        $('#cursor').html('<span style="font-size:19px; color:rgb(205, 160, 1);">محصولات</span>');
                        var titleIndex0 = result.indexOf('<title>');
                        var titleIndex1 = result.indexOf('</title>');
                        var title      = result.substring(titleIndex0 + 7, titleIndex1);
                        $('title').html(title);
                        var currentAddressBar = window.location.pathname;
                        window.history.pushState({page : "آرین البرز / صفحه محصولات ", id : "logo"}, title, currentAddressBar+"/Products");
                            console.log('The State---> ' + window.history.state.page + '\nThe Id--> ' + window.history.state.id );
                        window.onpopstate = function(event){
                            Reset();
                            window.history.replaceState({ page : "رین البرز، نخستین سایت خرید و فروش محصولات سرمایشی و گرمایشی", id : null}, "آرین البرز / خانه",currentAddressBar);
                             //pushState({page : "آرین البرز، نخستین سایت خرید و فروش محصولات سرمایشی و گرمایشی"}, "آرین البرز، خانه", currentAddressBar);
                            $('title').html("آرین البرز، خانه");

                            console.log('The State---> ' + window.history.state.page + '\nThe Id--> ' + window.history.state.id );
                            //window.history.pushState(null, title, currentAddressBar);
                        }
                 //alert(currentAddressBar);
                    }
                });//Ajax

            }
            else {
                return; 
            }
            $(this)
                    .animate({
                        width:         WinWidth,
                        height:           WinHeight,
                        marginTop:   -85,
                        marginLeft:  -210
                    }, 100, 'easeOutQuint', false)
                    .data({ id: detail.id, class: detail.class, htmlCode: detail.htmlCode})
                    .css({'z-index':500, 'cursor':'default'})
                    .transition({rotateY:'360deg'}, 1000,'snap');

            $('html, body').css('overflow','hidden');


    });
    /*/-----  C L I C K    ON    DIV # L O G O  -----/*/






    /*/-----  C L I C K    ON    DIV # T O P    R I G H T ( C O N T A C T )  -----/*/
    $(document).on('click', 'div#topRight', function(){
          $('div.moraba, div.mostatil, div.big_moraba, div.arrows').not(this).stop(true).fadeOut('fast');


          if ( $(this).css('width') == '250px' ) {
              var detail = {};
              detail.id                 = $(this).attr('id');
              detail.class         = $(this).attr('class').substr(7);
              detail.htmlCode       = $(this).html();
              detail.top              = $(this).css('top');
              detail.left            = $(this).css('left');

                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:"pages/Ajax/contactUs.php",
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $(this).html('<img src="images/icons/Progressbar.gif" width="470" height="40"  alt="آرین البرز، تماس با ما"/>')
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        404: function(){
                            $(this).html('صفحه مورد نظر پیدا نشد');
                        }
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('div#topRight').html(result);
                        $('#cursor').html('<span style="font-size:19px; color:rgb(255, 10, 14);">ارتباط با ما</span>');

                        var currentAddressBar = window.location.pathname;
                          var titleIndex0 = result.indexOf('<title>');
                          var titleIndex1 = result.indexOf('</title>');
                          var title    = result.substring(titleIndex0 + 7, titleIndex1);

                        var thisID = detail.id;

                        window.history.pushState({page : "آرین البرز / تماس با ما", id : thisID }, title, currentAddressBar + '/contactUs');

                        $('title').html(title);
                        //$('<link rel="shortcut icon" href="arianalborz.ico">arianalborz.ico</a>').appendTo('head')
                        console.log(currentAddressBar + '\n Title--> ' + title + '\n State--> ' + window.history.state.page + '\n ID--> ' + thisID );

                         window.onpopstate = function(event){
                             Reset();
                             window.history.replaceState({ page : "رین البرز، نخستین سایت خرید و فروش محصولات سرمایشی و گرمایشی", id : null}, "آرین البرز / خانه",currentAddressBar);
                              //pushState({page : "آرین البرز، نخستین سایت خرید و فروش محصولات سرمایشی و گرمایشی"}, "آرین البرز، خانه", currentAddressBar);
                             $('title').html("آرین البرز، خانه");

                             console.log('The State---> ' + window.history.state.page + '\nThe Id--> ' + window.history.state.id );
                             //window.history.pushState(null, title, currentAddressBar);
                         }


                    }
                });//Ajax


          }
          else {
             return ; 
          }
          $(this)
            .animate({
                width:         WinWidth,
                height:           WinHeight,
                marginTop:   -85,
                marginLeft:  -263,
            }, 100, 'easeOutQuint', false)
            .data({ id: detail.id, class: detail.class, htmlCode: detail.htmlCode})
            .css({'z-index':500, 'cursor':'default'})
            .transition({rotateY:'360deg'}, 1000,'snap', false);


            $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: 850}, 'fast', 'swing', false).css('overflow', 'hidden');
    });

    /*/-----  C L I C K    ON    DIV # T O P    R I G H T ( C O N T A C T )  -----/*/









    /*/----- S T A R T    I C O N    C L I C K -----/*/
     $('#start_menu').click(function(e) {
         //Reset();
         window.history.back();
     });
    /*/----- S T A R T    I C O N    C L I C K -----/*/


    /*/----  F U N C T I O N      R E S E T  -----/*/

         function Reset() {

        $('div.mostatil#logo').fadeIn('fast').html($('#logo').data('htmlCode'));
        $('div#maqhalat, div#topRight, div.big_moraba, div.arrows').fadeIn('fast')

        $('.moraba').fadeIn('fast').each(function(index, element) {
          if ( $(this).data('id') == 'undefined' || $(this).data('id') == null ) {
                  return;
              }
              else {

                  var id,width,height,top,left,marginLeft,marginTop;
                  id         = $(this).data('id');
                  width      = $(this).data('width');
                  height       = $(this).data('height');
                  top             = $(this).data('top');
                  left           = $(this).data('left');
                  marginLeft = $(this).data('marginLeft');
                  marginTop = $(this).data('marginTop');

                  htmlCode  = $(this).data('htmlCode');
                  //alert(htmlCode);
                  $('#'+id).fadeOut(700, 'easeOutQuint', function(){
                      $(this).removeAttr('style').removeClass('rotate').css('transition','all 1s').fadeIn(400);
                      $(this)
                  });


                  $('#'+id).html(htmlCode);
                  $(this).removeData();
                  $('#cursor').html('پنجره اصلی سایت آرین البرز')

                  $('body').css('overflow','visible');
      }
        });//moraba').each

        if ( $('#logo').data('id') != "undefined" || $('#logo').data('id') != null ) {
            //alert( 'yes' );
            $('#logo').animate({width:250, height:120, marginTop:0, marginLeft:0}, 'easeInOutQuint', false)
                         .transition({rotateY:'0deg'}, 1000,'snap')
                         .css({'background':'linear-gradient(to right,rgb(214,164,1), rgb(204,160,1))', 'cursor': 'pointer'})
                         .removeData();

            $('#cursor').html('پنجره اصلی سایت آرین البرز');
        }
        else {
            return; 
        };

        if ( $('#topRight').data('id') != "undifined" || $('#topRight').data('id') != null ) {
            var htmlCode = $('#topRight').data('htmlCode');
            $('div#topRight').animate({width:250, height:120, marginTop:0, marginLeft:130}, 'easeInOutQuint', false)
                            .transition({rotateY:'0deg'}, 1000,'snap')
                            .css({'cursor': 'pointer', 'z-index':0})
                            .removeData()
                            .html(htmlCode);
        }
        else {
            return;
        };

          if ( WinWidth > 1600 ) {
              $('html, body')
                          .animate({scrollTop: 0, scrollLeft: 0}, 700, 'easeOutQuint')
                          .css('overflow','auto')
                          .find('.arrows#part2_left')
                                      .fadeOut('slow')
                                      .parents('body')
                                      .find('.arrows#part2_right').fadeIn('slow');

          }//if ( winWidth > 1600
          else {
              $('.arr').not('div#part2_left').fadeOut('fast');
              $('div#part2_left').fadeIn('fast');
          }
    }
  //});//#start_menu').click
    /*/-----  F U N C T I O N   R E S E T  -----/*/

});
```

Comment: You might want to ask four separate questions. And you will need to provide the relevant code for each, [a link is not sufficient](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/)

Comment: there are more than 7 files with thousands of lines, and I can't add more than this because of site restriction... you might use `firebug` and `developer tools` to see all files, if you want to help...

Comment: I am facing the same problem.. did you find the answeer?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting `js`. If possible, can post `css` and `html` ?

Not certain about each listed issue. Will try to address those noticed.

***1/, A=>***

> 1/ When user click on cubes, they will transform 360 deg and became
>   full screen... -Kiyarash
>
> A=> The cubes that marked with (( don't work )) -Kiyarash

```
.transition({rotateY:'360deg'}, 1500,'snap');
```

`.transition()` not, that aware of, a valid `jquery` `method`, that is, does not appear mapped to `jquery` by an `$.fn.extend()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/ "declaration". Also, the `css` `property` for `rotateY`, that aware of, is `transform`, instead of `transition`. Unless unaware of specific included library that has defined a `.transition()` method.

Try

`.css({"transform":"rotateY(360deg)", "-webkit-transform":"rotateY(360deg)" ..})`

***I=>***

> I=> The favicon disappear in google chrome33 and opera20 and Internet
>   Explorer11 after Ajax request and when the page title will
>   update...!!!-Kiyarash

Try

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" src="data:image/png;base64,.." />
```

or in (an) `$.ajax()` `callback` try

```
$("link[rel^=shortcut]").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,..")
```

Edit (updated)

Noticed this piece, also

```
$('.moraba').fadeIn('fast').each(function(index, element) {
  if ( $(this).data('id') == 'undefined' || $(this).data('id') == null ) {
          return;
      }
      else { ..
```

At `html` document, with `jquery` ("1.10.2") loaded, and *without* jquery's `.data()` method defined or containing values for the given element, at console, try

```
$("html").data("id") == "undefined" // -> `false`

$("html").data("id") == undefined // -> `true`
```

Perhaps a prospective solution may be to break each `block` into individual "pieces", and test (`debug`) each individually ?

Thanks for sharing.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your attention, actually `jQuery.transit` works fine for me and that's not my problem... I need a complete detailed answer for all concerns, but about the second part of your answer, it seems right and I'll give you +1... please help me about all of issues if possible...

Comment: @Kiyarash Perhaps, fair amount to review. Not tried `html5 history API`. If possible, please post link to `jQuery.transit` documentation. See also, updated post. Thanks for sharing

Comment: You can find `jQuery.transit` in this link:
https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit

Answer (score 0):

You basicly want to reprogram the PJAX library, I suggest you have a look at it at: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

You can either implement it, which I would recommend since it's a huge effort to reprogramm it + it's fully degradable! Or you can look at its source to understand the history part!

Hope it helps,
Cheers